# How to preserve a list in a loop after calling remove() method

Tags: list

I am trying to generate a set of questions using a dictionary of questions and correct answer. (Ques about state and their capital, multiple choice type)
First, I try to create another list to contain dictionaries which key is the state's name, and value is a list contain 4 choices, including a correct and 3 random ones. I am stuck at generating 3 random false answers. My idea is to get it from the input dictionary, by first remove the correct pair, then remove the 1 false pair, then the 2nd and the 3rd, so as to achieve 4 different ans.
The problem I am using for loop, and everytime I come back to the beginning of another loop, the dictionary no longer stay the same but is reduced by 4 items (the correct and 3 false ones). And I couldn't go to the end of my loop for 'index out of range'.
I try to replicate the original dictionary and only modify on the replication but both are modified.

Here is my code:

def create_question(original_list):
    import random
    ques_and_ans = []

```
list_modified = original_list

for i in range(len(original_list)):
    list_modified = original_list
    pair = original_list[i]
    a_question = {}

    state = pair[0] #the pair is provided in the format ('state','capital')
    correct_answer = pair[1]
    list_modified.remove(pair)

    fake1 = random.choice(list_modified)
    list_modified.remove(fake1)
    fake2 = random.choice(list_modified)
    list_modified.remove(fake2)
    fake3 = random.choice(list_modified)
    list_modified.remove(fake3)
    answer_list = [correct_answer, fake1[1], fake2[1], fake3[1]]
    a_question = {state: answer_list}
    ques_and_ans.append(a_question)
```

Comment: Have you tried `for pair in original_list: ...`? This should iterate over the list without having to take into account an index. But I am not sure how python deals with this approach. (For example, java throws a ConcurrentModificationException)

Comment: THanks Cristian, I tried that, but it's only simplify the code without solving the problem of preserving list. btw, it's nice to know that method of iterating, very effective. I'm new in Python :D.